# Cutting off textscan after a character

Tags: matlab, file-io, comments, textscan

I'm working on a function in MATLAB that reads input from a file. So far (after reading a bit here about `scanf` vulnerabilities) I decided to use `fgets` to get each line, and then `textscan` to extract the words, which will always be of the format 'chars' including the apostrophes. So, I'm using:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
tline = fgets(fid);
textscan(tline, '''%s''');
```

However, I want to allow people to have comments, using the % character. How do I cut off `textscan` so that

```
'word' 'anotherword' % 'comment'
```

doesn't return comment?

Comment: What people? You should try to clarify, because without knowing the context it's confusing.

Comment: @WebfootWitchHat People making the text file that I'm reading from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
tline = fgets(fid);
pct = find(tline=='%');
tline(pct(1)-1:end)=[]; % deletes tline from first instance of '%' onward.
textscan(tline, '''%s''');
```

Note that the above will cut off after any `%` at all in the line, even if it is in quotes.

If you want to allow the character % in your quoted string yous you have to do more logic on testing for comment % before deleting rest of tline.  Look at the `strcmp` and `findstr` functions which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more reading around while debugging, I found a more straightforward way to do this.

```
textscan(tline, '''%s''', 'commentStyle', '%');
```